# Link the current user to a field in ModelForm django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a commerce site using django. The logged in user has the ability to create a listing. I'm using django model to create a model and ModelForm for forms.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    listed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The last field in `Listing(models.Model)` is used to store the user who listed the listing which should be based on the current logged in user.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Listing


class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ["title", "description", "starting_bid", "image_url", "category"]
```

`forms.py` without the `listed_by` field is working as intended.

views.py

```
def create(request):
    """Renders a Form to Create a Listing"""

    if request.method == "POST":

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ListingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Save a new Listing object from the form's data.
            listing = form.save()

            # Redirects the users to the main page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

        # If the form is not valid, render the template with errors
        return render(request, 'auctions/create_listing.html', {"form": form})

    # Create a form instance and pass it to the template
    form = ListingForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/create_listing.html", {"form": form})
```

Here, I classified how I handle this form.

**Problem**

My problem arises when I want to link the current logged in user to `Listing` model, so I've searched for answers which unfortunately didn't clear my concerns due to the fact that I'm using a ModelForm.

What have I tried?
I've read the documentation on this and the stackoverflow's answers among them:

- [Django Documentation (Models and request.user)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)
- [get current user for 'created_by' field in model class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52871997)
- [How to auto insert the current user when creating an object in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2991365)

Is the proposed links the best approach to my problem? If so, how should I use it? Should I use it in *models.py*, *forms.py* or *views.py*?

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach you can take to solve your problem is by adding `listed_by` in `views.py`.

According the [Django's Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

> If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database... This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it...

so in `views.py` add the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Save a new Listing object from the form's data.
    listing = form.save()

    listing.listed_by = request.user
    listing.save()

    # Redirects the users to the main page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a model object without saving it and add to it using `commit=False`

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Save a new Listing object from the form's data.
    listing = form.save(commit=False)
    listing.listed_by = request.user
    listing.save()
```